# freeRTOS timer keep working in power save mode and active mode

Tags: timer, freertos, sleep-mode

I have one device need report an event every 30 mins when first boot up.

In this period device could enter power saving mode or wake up form power saving mode.

e.g.

Times| Event

---

10:00  device first boot up

10:05  device enter sleep mode

10:20  device wake up by interrupt

10:25  device enter sleep mode

10:30  device wake up due to timer timeout

10:35  device enter sleep mode

...

11:00  device wake up due to timer timeout

I tried create timer in task but it always suspend when enter power saving mode.

Could freeRTOS create a timer that could keep working between power saving mode and active mode?

Comment: What hardware are you using?